# Sending emails to unverified addresses

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have searched www for this answer, but I couldn't find it. So:

I have some platform, where admin can add new users to db. I would like to use AWS SES to send email to this created user, and send him his credentials - something like 'Welcome to my service, your username is username, and password is password'.

Until now, I had no issues with hooking up SES to my server. I can send my email to the emails that are verified - but I cannot find a way to send an email to the address that hasn't been verified. What am I missing here? Can I send emails only to the addresses that are verified? Does that mean that I cannot create this functionality?

To be more precise:

I have added two verified emails:

```
email1@gmail.com
email2@gmail.com
```

I can send email from `email1` to `email2`, and the other way around. However, I cannot send an email from either of verified addresses to `email3`, This is the error:

> Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the
>   check in region EU-WEST-1: email3@gmail.com (Service:
>   AmazonSimpleEmailService;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Amazon SES Email address is not verified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22128800/amazon-ses-email-address-is-not-verified)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, I've found an answer [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-addresses-and-domains.htmlhttp://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-addresses-and-domains.html):

> Before you can send an email using Amazon SES, you must verify the address or domain that you are sending the email from to prove that you own it. If your account is still in the Amazon SES sandbox, you also need to verify any email addresses that you send emails to except for email addresses provided by the Amazon SES mailbox simulator. You can verify an email address or domain by using the Amazon SES console or by using the Amazon SES API.

My account is in sandbox, and hence I cannot send email to an email which is not verified.