# Get Error Code For Unverified Identities In SendMail Exception AWS SES PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am currently catching an exception for when an identity is not verified using the following code -

```
use Aws\Ses\SesClient;
use Aws\Ses\Exception;

try {
       $result = $ses->sendEmail($data);
} catch (Exception $e) {

    echo $e->getResponse();

}
```

It prints out the following -

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Aws\Ses\Exception\SesException' 
with message 'Error executing "SendEmail" on "https://email.us-
west-2.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST 
https://email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` 
response:

<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
    <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>MessageReje (truncated...)
    MessageRejected (client): Email address is not verified. The 
following identities failed the check in region US-WEST-2: 
arn:aws:ses:us-west-2:**************** - <ErrorResponse 
xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
    <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>MessageRejected</Code>
    <Message>Email address is not verified. The following identities 
failed the check in region US-WEST-2: arn:aws:ses:us-
west-2:************</Message>
    </Error>
  <RequestId>*****************</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>

exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException' with  in /var/www
/html/data/aws/Aws/WrappedHttpHandler.php on line 159
```

I cannot get any of the methods outlined on the following page to print out anything different -

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.Ses.Exception.SesException.html

Any ideas how I can get an actual error code out of this exception so that I can take the appropriate action in the rest of my script?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22128800/amazon-ses-email-address-is-not-verified

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct namespace? `Aws\Ses\Exception\SesException` is shown in the documentation. You might want to alias the Exception one as @Dekel hints at. Since you are namespacing `Aws\Ses\Exception` you can try to catch for `SesException` and handle it there.

Answer (score 0):

In order to catch all exceptions you better use

```
} catch (\Exception $e) {
```

To make sure you don't get the wrong `Exception` class from the wrong namespace.

Regarding the problem that you are hitting - when using [Amazon SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) to send Emails you must first [verify your email/domain](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-email-addresses.html) (note that any of `From, source, sender, return-path` headers can cause you a problem if not verified).

If you can post some information regarding your `$ses` object or the `$data` you use it might help.

Answer (score 0):

**[Class MessageRejectedException](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.Ses.Exception.MessageRejectedException.html)** Indicates that the action failed, and the message could not be sent. Check the error stack for more information about what caused the error.

```
Exception
    Extended by RuntimeException
        Extended by Aws\Common\Exception\RuntimeException implements Aws\Common\Exception\AwsExceptionInterface
            Extended by Aws\Common\Exception\ServiceResponseException
                Extended by Aws\Ses\Exception\SesException
                    Extended by Aws\Ses\Exception\MessageRejectedException
```

Try this -> use Aws\Ses\Exception\MessageRejectedException;
or use Aws\Ses\Exception\SesException; and replace class name into catche block

Bcause Aws\Ses\Exception is namespace of class MessageRejectedException.
you have to use class with namespace ,not only namespace.

```
use Aws\Ses\SesClient;
use Aws\Ses\Exception\MessageRejectedException;

try {
       $result = $ses->sendEmail($data);
} catch (MessageRejectedException $e) {

    echo $e->getResponse();

}
```

I hope helped.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$e->getAwsErrorCode();`

Methods inherited from Aws\Exception\AwsException
`__construct()`, `__toString()`, `get()`, `getAwsErrorCode()`, `getAwsErrorMessage()`, `getAwsErrorShape()`, `getAwsErrorType()`, `getAwsRequestId()`, `getCommand()`, `getRequest()`, `getResponse()`, `getResult()`, `getStatusCode()`, `getTransferInfo()`, `hasKey()`, `isConnectionError()`, `isMaxRetriesExceeded()`, `search()`, `setMaxRetriesExceeded()`, `setTransferInfo()`

You can see the `SesExeption` API from AWS link is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.Ses.Exception.SesException.html